# Enthought Canopy Lock Error

Tags: canopy

I have been using Enthought Canopy for quite a while now with the academic license. Till yesterday it was working fine. But now when I try to open it, it is showing

```
 LockError: Lock could not be acquired
```

Here is a complete summary of the bug report generated by Canopy:

```
Subject: Failed to setup your environment
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1989, in main
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1021, in main
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1012, in _kill_leftover_procs
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\running_process_manager.py", line 116, in kill_leftover_procs
File "C:\Users\Dipto\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.1.0.1371.win-x86_64\lib\contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
return self.gen.next()
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\running_process_manager.py", line 59, in lock
LockError: Lock could not be acquired
```

I am using the 64-bit version of Canopy on Windows 7.

How can I get Canopy to work again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log out of Windows, log back in again, then delete any of the following files (if they exist) from `C:\Users\Dipto\Appdata\Roaming\Enthought\Canopy\`:

```
proc_manager.lock
process.lck
running_procs.pkl
```

Then restart Canopy.

Then I suggest that you update to 1.1.1, which usually handles this automatically (though on occasion it may still be necessary to log out / log in before Windows itself will release a locked file.)